# what is someone ''who mentions and repeats their help to us again and again'' called?

Tags: translation

In my language there is an adjective and a verb for somebody who mentions their help repeatedly and every time they see you. This word is used to show disapproval. The dictionary translations are ''throw it in someone's face'' and ''cast in someone's teeth'' which, when I check in a monolingual dictionary, don't make sense.

For example:

- I was the one who introduced you to that company.
- Remember the time I take your children to school when you didn't have time
- If it wasn't for me, they'd never accepted you.

in addition, this person doesn't necessarily need a favor back. just wants to say if it wasn't for him you weren't able to do that and you have to thank them over and over. they just crave being thanked constantly.and you can't argue or fight with them because once you start they bring that issue up and blame you for being ungrateful.

I was wondering if there was a word in English that means the same.

Comment: Have you looked in a bilingual dictionary? It sometimes helps if you tell us the word in your native language, as there may be bilingual people who can help.

Comment: @james I've checked but they give me some answers that when I check in a monolingual dictionary It doesn't make sense. ''throw it in someone's face'' and ''cast in someone's teeth''.

Comment: Cast in someones face is not a common current idiom, and means to remind someone of the wrongs that they have done. see the ELU question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103365/activity-adjective-for-keep-re-mentioning-a-favor

Answer (score 1):

You might call such a person an "ungracious giver" or someone who "hold things over your head". You could also try saying they are "milking it for all it's worth
". I can't think of a single word though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A phrase that would be suitable and understood would be, "They keep bringing it up."

It doesn't translate directly to someone consistently mentioning that they helped you; it's used more broadly than that.  It does, however, carry negative connotations in that someone keeps talking about something they hold over you or know you don't want to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are asking for a simple noun and adjective to "characterize" the person, but mostly we use phrases to describe the act of doing it.

Some good ones have already been posted...  You could also say they are "**beating you over the head with it**" ... or ... "**beating you up over it**" ... or ... they "**just won't let it go**" ... or ... you are "**taking a drubbing**" over it, although this last one is more old-fashioned.  Also ... they are "**hanging onto it**" ... or to make fun of them ... "**hanging onto it for dear life**" ... like you would hang onto a rope if you fell off of a ship.